# Trying to read an Excel file file stream in C#, I get numbers instead of text

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, memorystream

I'm trying to use DocumentFormat.OpenXml to read an uploaded Excel file. When I get the file (HttpPosteFileWrapper) I'm simply trying to read the cells and write them to a text string. (Later I will do more, but I'm just trying to get used to OpenXml right now.)

My data in Excel looks something like this:

> Field1        - Field2 - Phone      - City
>   IT Department - Emp    - 7175551234 - Springfield
>   HR            - Emp    - 7175556543 - W Springfield

Code looks like this:

```
var doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(file.InputStream, false);
WorkbookPart workbookPart = doc.WorkbookPart;
WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
SheetData thisSheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();
System.Text.StringBuilder text = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
foreach (Row r in thisSheet.Elements<Row>())
{
    foreach (Cell c in r.Elements<Cell>())
    {
        text.Append(c.CellValue.Text + ",");
    }
    text.AppendLine();
}
```

And the string it creates looks like this:

> 49,51,50,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,16,14,15,17,18,19,20,21,22,40,41,42,43,44,45,54,\r\n
>   52,24,23,25,26,27,7306,33,28,29,30,31,17033,32,34,7175555555,7175551234,7175554321,7175550000,35,36,37,36526,40179,38,39,30,31,17033,32,55,\r\n
>   53,46,47,48,555,\r\n

It seems like the numeric values come through. Is it because I'm using the wrong stream type?

*Edit:* I've updated my code to now look like this, but it still doesn't work right. There seems to be no way for me to see the text data.

```
public ActionResult ProfileImport(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    // Build file list
    int i = 1;
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {

var doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(file.InputStream, false);
WorkbookPart workbookPart = doc.WorkbookPart;
WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
SheetData thisSheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();
System.Text.StringBuilder text = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
foreach (Row r in thisSheet.Elements<Row>())
{
    foreach (Cell c in r.Elements<Cell>())
    {
        string value = c.InnerText;
        if (c.DataType != null && c.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString) // Check DataType exists
        {
            var stringTable = workbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>()
                .FirstOrDefault(); // Get Table parts from workbookPart
            if (stringTable != null)
                value = stringTable.SharedStringTable.ElementAt(int.Parse(value)).InnerText;
            text.Append(value + ",");
        }
        else
            text.Append(value + ",");
     }
     text.AppendLine();
 }
 var outText = text.ToString();
}
}
}
```

Actual data from 1st row of the file:
AddressDescription, Address1, Address2, City, State, PostalCode, CountryCode, Email, CellPhone, HomePhone, WorkPhone, Fax, OrganizationName, Department, Position, StartDate, EndDate, OrganizationAddress1, OrganizationAddress2   OrganizationCity, OrganizationState, OrganizationPostalCode, OrganizationCountryCode, Keywords

Row.InnerText of that row:
"49515001234567891011121316141517181920212240414243444554"

Row.OuterXml:

```
"<x:row r=\"1\" spans=\"1:33\" s=\"3\" customFormat=\"1\" x14ac:dyDescent=\"0.25\" xmlns:x14ac=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac\" xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main\">
    <x:c r=\"A1\" s=\"3\" t=\"s\"><x:v>49</x:v></x:c>
    <x:c r=\"B1\" s=\"3\" t=\"s\"><x:v>51</x:v></x:c>
    <x:c r=\"C1\" s=\"3\" t=\"s\"><x:v>50</x:v></x:c>
    <x:c r=\"D1\" s=\"3\" t=\"s\"><x:v>0</x:v></x:c>
    <x:c r=\"E1\" s=\"3\" t=\"s\"><x:v>1</x:v></x:c>
    <x:c r=\"F1\" s=\"3\" t=\"s\"><x:v>2</x:v></x:c>
    <x:c r=\"G1\" s=\"3\" t=\"s\"><x:v>3</x:v></x:c>
    <x:c r=\"H1\" s=\"3\" t=\"s\"><x:v>4</x:v></x:c>
    <x:c r=\"I1\" s=\"3\" t=\"s\"><x:v>5</x:v></x:c>
    <x:c r=\"J1\" s=\"3\" t=\"s\"><x:v>6</x:v></x:c>
    <x:c r=\"K1\" s=\"3\" t=\"s\"><x:v>7</x:v></x:c>
    <x:c r=\"L1\" s=\"3\" t=\"s\"><x:v>8</x:v></x:c>
    <x:c r=\"M1\" s=\"3\" t=\"s\"><x:v>9</x:v></x:c>
    <x:c r=\"N1\" s=\"3\" t=\"s\"><x:v>10</x:v></x:c>
    <x:c r=\"O1\" s=\"3\" t=\"s\"><x:v>11</x:v></x:c>
    <x:c r=\"P1\" s=\"4\" t=\"s\"><x:v>12</x:v></x:c>
    <x:c r=\"Q1\" s=\"4\" t=\"s\"><x:v>13</x:v></x:c>
    <x:c r=\"R1\" s=\"3\" t=\"s\"><x:v>16</x:v></x:c>
    <x:c r=\"S1\" s=\"3\" t=\"s\"><x:v>14</x:v></x:c>
    <x:c r=\"T1\" s=\"3\" t=\"s\"><x:v>15</x:v></x:c>
    <x:c r=\"U1\" s=\"3\" t=\"s\"><x:v>17</x:v></x:c>
    <x:c r=\"V1\" s=\"3\" t=\"s\"><x:v>18</x:v></x:c>
    <x:c r=\"W1\" s=\"3\" t=\"s\"><x:v>19</x:v></x:c>
    <x:c r=\"X1\" s=\"3\" t=\"s\"><x:v>20</x:v></x:c>
    <x:c r=\"Y1\" s=\"3\" t=\"s\"><x:v>21</x:v></x:c>
    <x:c r=\"Z1\" s=\"3\" t=\"s\"><x:v>22</x:v></x:c>
    <x:c r=\"AA1\" s=\"3\" t=\"s\"><x:v>40</x:v></x:c>
    <x:c r=\"AB1\" s=\"3\" t=\"s\"><x:v>41</x:v></x:c>
    <x:c r=\"AC1\" s=\"3\" t=\"s\"><x:v>42</x:v></x:c>
    <x:c r=\"AD1\" s=\"3\" t=\"s\"><x:v>43</x:v></x:c>
    <x:c r=\"AE1\" s=\"3\" t=\"s\"><x:v>44</x:v></x:c>
    <x:c r=\"AF1\" s=\"3\" t=\"s\"><x:v>45</x:v></x:c>
    <x:c r=\"AG1\" s=\"3\" t=\"s\"><x:v>54</x:v></x:c>
</x:row>"
```

Comment: It's been awhile since I've worked wtih spreadsheets in .net.. I recall using the Range object quite a bit..

Comment: The file is an xlsx worksheet file.

Comment: Are you able to determine the `DataType` of the cells for which you can't get the string data?

Comment: c.DataType is 's'. Huh? In Excel the file cells are all 'General'.

Comment: Tried setting some columns/fields to 'Text', still come up as numbers.

Comment: "s" is `CellValues.SharedString`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.cellvalues(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: What does the new code return?

Comment: I can get the text now. It is a SharedString, but the example was pointing me to the wrong location. Instead of getting the SharedStringTablePart from the worksheetPart, I need to get it from the workbookPart.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like these are indices to the strings in the Shared Strings table.  In Excel file formats, string data is stored in a shared strings table, which is then references on the cell level.  Per the documentation, `CellValue` returns an index to the `StringTable` if the data type is text.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.cellvalue%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Not knowing more about the type of data that's in your cells (there are different ways to retrieve it based on the data type).  If it's what I think it is, it'll be a `SharedString`, which you will need to retrieve as a SharedStringTablePart, as shown in this MSDN page:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh298534%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Your code would look something like this:

```
foreach (Cell c in r.Elements<Cell>())
{
    string value = c.InnerText;
    if (c.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)
    {
        var stringTable = workbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>()
            .FirstOrDefault();
        if (stringTable != null)
            value = stringTable.SharedStringTable.ElementAt(int.Parse(value)).InnerText;
        text.Append(value + ",");
    }
    else
        text.Append(value + ",");
    text.AppendLine();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code sample. However, while the cells do say they are SharedString, the stringTable is always 'null'. Also, where you say theCell.InnerText do you mean c.InnerText;?

Comment: Yes, I did!  I had adapted from some code that I had written to test the shared string table hypothesis.  But I only copied the code on the page to give you a chance to see it.  The entire logic is based on code from the MSDN link, which is a self-contained class to get the values from Excel cells.  If you would take a look at that class, it may be able to extract the values for you.

Comment: Also, the InnerText is sometimes the correct data. If the value of the data is numeric, like a phone number, InnerText reflects that correctly.

Comment: Absolutely, the check for `SharedString` value type is meant to prevent you from searching the shared string table for those values.  In that case it should default to the `InnerText` value.

Comment: I had read the two posts you mention before posting my question here. I don't think this is going to work for me. I think it expects XML data, and this is an Excel worksheet.

Comment: .xlsx worksheets are writen in the Office Open XML format -- the format that is accessed using the API that you are using.  So it is in fact both an Excel worksheet and XML data.  The information on the links is for getting the values of cells written in that format, which you're already using on your code sample, so I think you will find it useful.

Comment: You need to get the stringTable from workBookPart, not workSheetPart. Then it works fine, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 5):

I Have the same problem and found the solution, you just need to add this method, you will get the exact text that you need, not the numbers:

```
        private string ReadExcelCell(Cell cell, WorkbookPart workbookPart)
        {
            var cellValue = cell.CellValue;
            var text = (cellValue == null) ? cell.InnerText : cellValue.Text;
            if ((cell.DataType != null) && (cell.DataType == CellValues.SharedString))
            {
                text = workbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable
                    .Elements<SharedStringItem>().ElementAt(
                        Convert.ToInt32(cell.CellValue.Text)).InnerText;
            }
            return (text ?? string.Empty).Trim();
        }
```